# split file contents based on regex: python

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I want to keep each rule (rule1,rule2,rule3) in a list . example file:https://github.com/Yara-Rules/rules/blob/master/malware/APT_WildNeutron.yar
I am using the following code

```
patt=re.compile("\s*[\n]*rule.*[\n]*\s*.*{")

results=re.split(r'\s*[\n]*rule.*[\n]*\s*.*{.', buf)
```

results does not contain the list.but it looks like like split is not working.
Can anybody help on this?

**-----------file contents-------**

```
rule rule1{

meta: 

 desc-test1


}

rule rule2{

meta: 

desc-test2


}

rule rule3{

meta: 

desc-test3


}
```

**----file end----------**
**expected output**

inside a rule there can be "rule strings". So a rule should be identified as 
**rule ruleName{**content can be anything includes new line words any string**}**. rule content would be limited by curly braces. I should be able to extract the rules into list. rules[0] should contain rule 1 and its contents. similarly for rule2.

Comment: This question is unclear, please add the output you *expect*.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> results=re.split(r'\s*[\n]*rule.*[\n]*\s*.*{.', buf)
> ```

1. Your pattern didn't match because the content-initiating `{` in your input is immediately followed by `\n`, and `.` without `re.DOTALL` doesn't match `\n`.
2. In `\s*[\n]*`, the `[\n]*` is useless because `\s` already matches `\n`.
3. Since you want the rule name also returned, you needn't include it in the split pattern.

So,

```
results = re.split(r'\brule\s+', buf)[1:]
```

should do (the `[1:]` discards the part before the first `rule`).